# Orthogonal complement of a subspace of $\ell^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Question: Describe the orthogonal complement of the following subspaces of $\ell^{2}$:

$M_{1} = \{x\in \ell^{2} : \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x_n} {n} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x_n} {n^{2}} = 0\}$

$M_{2} = \{x\in \ell^{2} :$ there is $n_{0} \in \mathbf{N}$ such that $x_{n} = 0$ for all $n \ge n_{0}$$\}$

For the second one, am I correct to say that the orthogonal complement is simply just all the sequences $y_{n}$ in $\ell^{2}$ such that $\exists n_{0} \in \mathbf{N} : y_{n} = 0$ for each $n < n_{0}$?

The first one is the one im having real trouble with. From my understanding, I need to figure out what types of sequences $y_{n}$ in $\ell^{2}$ will yield $<y,x>=0$. In other words, we need $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |{x_n}y_n|=0$ for every $x \in M_{1}$. But I really dont know how to figure out which sequences will do this for me, from the given conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that we are in $\ell^2,$ so which means that both the sequence $S_1$ of $\frac1n$ and $S_2$ of $\frac1{n^2}$ are in the space. Thus, any linear combination of $S_1$ and $S_2$ works (and only those).

Comment: Ah I see! But why are those the only sequences which work? Is it something to do with the orthogonal complement being a closed linear subspace or is there a simpler answer?

Comment: @duelspace Correct, and this is about as simple an answer as you can hope for (basically, you are using the fact that the orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement is the subspace itself).

Comment: I don't immediately see why this implies those are the only sequences which work. This orthogonal complement is a closed linear subspace, and we know $S_1$, $S_2$ belong to it.. but why does the closed property imply they are the only ones?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: observe that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{x_n}{n}=\langle x,y \rangle
$$

for $x:=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots )$ and $y:=(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots )$.